# How can I change the project health icon to reflect the status of the master branch?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have multiple projects in Jenkins built atop the pipelines and polls Github to build the `master`, `develop` and any associated pull-requests.

The health icon (the sunny, cloudy, stormy icons) use the worst performing to build to show the health of the project. Can I switch this health metric to only reflect the status of `master` as that is the most critical branch?

[image]

Comment: This can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626687/how-jenkins-updates-the-weather-report-for-build-jobs If you are using pipelines you can write a groovy script which checks the build status of your master and set your appropriate wheater icon

Comment: Where you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

HOPE THIS HELPS :)

You can see health metrics and child health metrics sections in configuration page of Jenkins UI. [configuration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/089VR.jpg)

You can disable health metrics section if it is already configured.

And inside child health metrics section you can see a drop down with two metrics, [Child health metrics section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLOqr.jpg) select “Health of the primary branch of a repository” and save the configuration.

Now, the health icons or weather icons will only consider the master branch.

NOTE: I’m using Bitbucket Team/Project in Jenkins 2.249.3